# Android Kotlin Passing Data From Callback Class To Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi what is the best way of passing data from a callback function defined in a different class to your activity back to your activity. I am new to android development so sorry if some of this is obvious. I am using an SDK provided by Xsens and a bit of background basically they provide sensors which connect to your device via bluetooth and then stream data back to your device such as acceleration, orientation etc...

The way my code is written is I scan for the sensors, they are then listed on my app and I can press connect on each sensor. When the connected button is clicked the callback class is defined (mine is called `ConnectScannedDevice()`)

Inside this `ConnectScannedDevice` Class I have overridden the following function and written the below code

```
override fun onXsensDotDataChanged(address: String, XsensDotData: XsensDotData) {
    XsensDotData.acc.forEachIndexed() { index, value ->
        Log.d("Sensor Data Acceleration $index", value.toString())
    }

    XsensDotData.dq.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
        Log.d("Sensor Data Orientation $index", value.toString())
    }
}
```

This callback function is hit when I start measuring on the device by using the following code `connectedDevice.startMeasuring()` this is when the callback function is hit.

I have a `setOnClickListener` in my activity which then runs the above code to make the device start measuring.

What I now need to do is pass the data the callback function is logging to logcat back to the activity. What is the best way of passing the data the callback function is logging to my activity where the button was pressed.

In the SDK documentation it mentions `The XsensDotData object has implemented the Parcelable object from Java, so this object can be passed to another class by Broadcast event.`

When the device starts measuring it is a constant stream of data until I stop it from measuring, I need to pass all this data back to the activity. I am trying to display this data onto a graph.

Comment: From where are you passing this back to the activity? If this code is running inside the activity you can just write a field in the activity itself. Or you can pass the activity to `ConnectScannedDevice`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Im not passing the data back to the activity yet thats what I am trying to figure out. The code which start the measuring is written in the activity but the callback function is in a completely different class preventing me from creating a field in the activity. Would you suggest passing the activity to `ConnectScannedDevice`?

Comment: Look up "ViewModel", "LiveData" and "Repository". I think this is "**the best way**" to update a stream of data through to your activity. If you simply want to call functions in your class then getting a reference to the class in the activity is sufficient. However, you want to update a stream back into the activity: This is where you need "LiveData" (I think). Also, if this is app has a potential to grow, I strongly recommend using fragments from the beginning.

Comment: Hi I just spent the past hour looking into LiveData and followed a tutorial, in the tutorial he writes the following code in the activity 

`val factory = InjectorUtils.provideDeviceDataViewModelFactory()
   val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
      .get(DeviceDataViewModel::class.java)`

and then I would call `viewModel.addDeviceData(data)`

I want to have this code in my `ConnectScannedDevice` class instead of the activity but how would I get the activity context to pass in here `ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)`

Comment: I posted an answer. In the future try to tag the person you want to to address so that they get notified. For example if you want me to be notified then use @SuperSymmetry

Answer (score 0):

The following is **not** tested but it outlines the logic of creating a `LiveData` stream.

- In your `ConnectScannedDevice` class add a private `MutableLiveData<XsensDotData>` property (that you will update as data changes) and a `LiveData<XsensDotData>` that you will expose to the `ViewModel`.

```
    // This is changed internally (never expose a MutableLiveData)
    private var xSensorDataMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<XsensDotData>()

    // Changed switchMap() to map()
    var xSensorDataLiveData: LiveData<XsensDotData> =
        Transformations.map(xSensorDataMutableLiveData) { data ->
            data
    }
```

- When the data changes you want to update your `xSensorMutableDataLiveData` in the `onXsensDotDataChanged` function

```
    override fun onXsensDotDataChanged(address: String, xSensDotData: XsensDotData) {
        xSensorDataMutableLiveData.value = XsensDotData
    }
```

- Now implement you `ViewModel` class as follows

```
// Uncomment if you want to use savedState
//class DeviceDataViewModel(private val savedState: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {
class DeviceDataViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    // define and initialize a ConnectScannedDevice property
    val connectScannedDevice = ConnecScannedDevice() // or however you initialize it
    // get a reference to its LiveData
    var xSensorDataLiveData = connectScannedDevice.xSensorDataLiveData
}
```

- In your activity get hold of the `ViewModel` like this

```
    private val deviceDataViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(DeviceDataViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

- Register your activity to observe the `LiveData` coming from the `ViewModel` in the `onCreate(Bundle?)` function and define how to respond

```
    deviceDataViewModel.xSensorDataLiveData.observe(
        this,
        Observer { xSensDotData ->
            xSensDotData.acc.forEachIndexed() { index, value ->
                Log.d("Sensor Data Acceleration $index", value.toString())
            }

            xSensDotData.dq.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
                Log.d("Sensor Data Orientation $index", value.toString())
            }
        }
    )
```

**Note**

Google recommends the use of a repository pattern, which means you should add a singleton repository class that does what your `ViewModel` is currently doing. Your `ViewModel` should then get hold of the repository instance and simply get its `LiveData` and pass it on to the activity.

The repository's job is to gather all data from all sources and pass them on to various `ViewModel`s. The `ViewModel` encapsulates the data needed by activities/fragments and helps make the data survive configuration changes. Activities and fragments get their data from `ViewModel`s and display them on screen.

Comment: thanks for providing this answer, I have tried using it in my code but the observer isnt logging anything im afraid. How is the observer being triggered because from looking at the code there is nothing for it to observe because the `deviceDataViewModel.xSensorDataLiveData` is never updated? Sorry if I am wring but for some reason the observer isnt being triggered I dont think

Comment: I have implemented the above code and had to change `switchMap` to `map` and it worked well. When you change `xSensorDataMutableLiveData.value` in your overriden `onXsensDotDataChanged` function, this triggers the `map` changing the value of `xSensorDataLiveData`, which then send this new value to the observing activity through the `ViewModel`. Hope this makes sense

Comment: You cannot update `deviceDataViewModel.xSensorDataLiveData` directly because `LiveData` is immutable and therefore, you have to update it through a transformation from a **private** `MutableLiveData`, which you can update as you wish.

Comment: How are you initialising `connectScannedDevice` in your `ViewModel`?